# v4l2loopback modprobe: module not found

Tags: camera, modprobe

I'm trying to use my DSLR as a webcam, I'm on an Arch linux system and therefor I have have installed `v4l-utils` and `v4l2loopback-dkms`.
But when i try to probe the v4l2loopback module, with the following command, I get an error saying that the module is not found:

```
$ sudo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1 max_buffers=2                                                                                                                
modprobe: FATAL: Module v4l2loopback not found in directory /lib/modules/5.7.12-arch1-1
```

I'm a bit stuck. Anyone having a suggestion on how to fix or debug this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing the `linux-headers` solved my problem.

Comment: Tip: to find the package to install linux headers: `apt search linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: I update linux headers but that does not resolve my problem.